# Rails : render and exit immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using the omniauth gem, I am forced to define a single route callback for succesful logins, regardless of the provider :

```
def auth_callback 

        auth_data = request.env['omniauth.auth']

        if auth_data.has_key('something')
            process_one(auth_data)
        else
            process_two(auth_data)
        end

        # No view is available here

end


def process_one
    # do something then render view for process_one
    return
end

def process_two
    # do something then render view for process_two
    return
end
```

How can I prevent the controller from returning to the auth_callback method and try to display the corresponding view (which does not exist) ? Treatment should be considered as complete once the process_one or process_two methods have returned.

Comment: Did you have code paths in your methods `process_one` and `process_two` which returns nothing? If so you can try to render :nothing=>true or something else there

Comment: I could use "if(x) render :process_one else render :process_two" in auth_callback, but it's quite unnatural : I'd rather rely on process_one and process_two to render their own views.

Comment: I meant if you write somewhere plain `return` (or have code like `return if(!something)`). Rails would try to render default action view

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743534/redirect-to-return/13575675#13575675

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Why not specifically call `render` in those methods?

```
def process_one
 # do something then render view for process_one
 render :process_one and return
end
```

Rails should detect that you've already run it and not try to render again.

Comment: Works. I thought Rails would try to render auth_callback even if a render had already been called. Many thanks.

Comment: Very practical to return from a controller method (no need to process the code below, typically after some validation).

Thank you :)

Comment: Since there's no logic after the render, is the `return` necessary in this case? In other words, is it okay if the method doesn't return nil but instead whatever `render` returns?

Comment: Right, you don't need to explicitly `return` here -- only if you have logic you want to skip after the call to render.

Comment: remember not to use `&&` instead of `and`

Comment: I'm surprised immediately returning isn't the default. Today I learned..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return from the chain of methods, e.g.

```
def a
  ...
  b
  ...
  render "smth"
end
...
def b
  ...
  # render from some conditional from here
  ...
end
```

will cause `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`, which means that you call `render` twice.

You can read this [article](https://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/4-ways-to-early-return-from-a-rails-controller/) to find out 4 ways to manage such situation.