# redirect_to != return

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for some clarification regarding the behaviour of `redirect_to`.

I have this code:

```
if some_condition
   redirect_to(path_one)
end

redirect_to(path_two)
```

If `some_condition == true` I get this error:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action.

It seems that the method continues to execute after the `redirect_to` call.  Do I need to write code like this:

```
if some_condition
   redirect_to(path_one)
   return
end

redirect_to(path_two)
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Yes, you need to return from method when doing redirect. It actually only adds appropriate headers for the response object.

You can write more rubyish way:

```
if some_condition
    return redirect_to(path_one)
end

redirect_to(path_two)
```

or other way:

```
return redirect_to(some_condition ? path_one : path_two)
```

or another way:

```
redirect_path = path_one

if some_condition
    redirect_path = path_two
end

redirect_to redirect_path
```

Answer (score 29):

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html:

> If you need to redirect on the
>   condition of something, then be sure
>   to add “and return” to halt execution.

```
def do_something
  redirect_to(:action => "elsewhere") and return if monkeys.nil?
  render :action => "overthere" # won't be called if monkeys is nil
end
```

Comment: What if, to structure your code nicer, you put the redirect in a private 'helper' method in the controller. I assume the return form inside that private method won't do the job, correct? What's the idiomatic way to handle that? Or do you have to put all the redirects in the top level of the controller action?

Comment: @pitosalas See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters. It says `If a "before" filter renders or redirects, the action will not run.`

Comment: Nowadays some people considers that it is a bad idea to use the operator `and` because of its counterintuitive precedence. In this case, the `and` works as intended but, still, _Rubocop_ would complain.

Answer (score 24):

You can also do

```
redirect_to path_one and return
```

which reads nice.

Comment: What happens here if redirect_to ever returns false or nil?  Doesn't that mean that the return statement would not be executed?  Or is that the intent?  The redirect_to docs don't specify what its return value is.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting there is *no* need to `return` unless you have any code after `redirect_to`, as in this example:

```
def show
  if can?(:show, :poll)
    redirect_to registrar_poll_url and return
  elsif can?(:show, Invoice)
    redirect_to registrar_invoices_url and return
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To consolidate the "rubyish way" example in [Eimantas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5743593/12484) to two lines of code:

```
return redirect_to(path_one) if some_condition

redirect_to(path_two)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to define the redirect within a method or helper function and early return in your controller:

[ActionController::Metal#performed?](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/performed%3F) - Tests if render or redirect has already happened:

```
def some_condition_checker
  redirect_to(path_one) if some_condition
end
```

**Call it like this:**

```
some_condition_checker; return if performed?

redirect_to(path_two)
```