# redirect_to vs redirect_to and return

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I doubt that if between both commands there's a difference, when I want to create an action without a view in rails I've always used `redirect_to` with no return after it and I've never had any problems, but until I forgot to put the `redirect_to` I realized that rails recommend to do a `redirect_to and return` if I don't want to have a view for the action, then I wonder, is there any difference when adding the return?, at least in my case I have never noticed any difference or error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect\_to != return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743534/redirect-to-return)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`redirect_to` will cause any automatic rendering to be skipped.

You only need the 'return' if you need to bypass further code in the action.  If the further code does an explicit `render`, then you must do a `return` to avoid an error of redirect and render both being present.

For example, a typical pattern in an `update` action might be...

```
def update
  @record = Record.new(record_params)
  if @record.save
    flash[:success] = "record was successfully saved"
    redirect_to records_path
    return
  end
  flash.now[:error] = "please fix the problems in the record"
  render :edit
end
```

Comment: In a case similar to yours where there is a redirect with a `return` needed to bypass code, is there any way to avoid creating a view template for that action? I'm getting an error due to a lack of template file

Comment: @user6313136 if you're getting a missing template file then you need to explicitly render what view you want.  In the example I posted, it's an `update` action which either redirects to the index (if successful) or renders the 'edit' view.  I don't have an update template but if I didn't explicitly render or redirect then rails would expect to render `update` view.  It would be non-typical to have an `update` view, though.