# Rails authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic redirect if false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect

I've got a very basic website i'm building for a friend, he requires a 'password' on a page and if the user isn't successful he wants it to redirect to a contact me page.

I've currently got this...

```
before_filter :authenticate

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
  if(username == "" && password == "***")
    true
  else
    redirect_to '/pages/contact'
  end
end
```

end

however it redirects to the contact page upon clicking on the link... how can I get it to prompt for the password?

Comment: I've since discovered the above code DOES work! However if you enter the wrong username and or password it redirects you to the contacts page. If you return to try again it will once again redirect you to the contact page..is it possible to stop that? clear the cache or something?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
before_filter :authenticate

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    redirect_to '/pages/contact' unless (username == "" && password == "***")
  end
end
```

Note:

Another suggestion, from your above code, I would like to suggest you to take a look this [discussion: redirect_to is not return in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743534/redirect-to-return) in order to avoid unexpected error.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've change the code to your suggestion. It essentially is the same outcome, it does work... however if you enter the username/password wrong it will no longer prompt for a username/password just always redirect... any ideas?

Comment: `how can I get it to prompt for the password?` Can you explain more what do you really want in case of the user enter wrong username / password in your sites ?

Comment: I essentially want it to ALWAYS prompt for a password, even if you have already successfully accessed the page.