# Ruby : return from calling method

Tags: ruby, return

I'd like to be able to return from the calling method while still inside the called method.

Example :

```
def calling_method
  # stuff
  called_method
  # more stuff
end

def called_method
  # stuff
  return_from_caller if foo # << I would like to return from calling_method
  # more stuff
end
```

Is there a simple way to achieve that ?

The "dirty" way I'm using at the moment is this :

```
def calling_method
  # stuff
  called_method and return
  # more stuff
end

def called_method
  # stuff
  return false if foo
  # more stuff
end
```

But this isn't fully satisfying as I have to do a `and return` in the calling method.

Comment: Ruby, like other languages, when get the return statement ends the method. You can set a variable with the content and return on the end of this method.

Comment: I honestly don't understand your comment. Could you provide a code example ?

Comment: You could also raise an exception, if that makes sense semantically.

Comment: Not in that case, but yeah, I've thought about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you can't do that.

The only way you can do that (at least I can think of right now) is, by using what you are calling `dirty` way of doing it.

Actually, `do_something and return` is a pretty common pattern/use case that you would see in Ruby/Rails code.

So, IMO, this is the way to go:

```
def calling_method
  # stuff
  called_method and return
  # more stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks. The fact that you tell me this is common reassures me a bit. I'll wait a few minutes to see if a better answer pops then upvote and choose your answer if not.

Comment: By the mean time, you can take a look at this post: http://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/4-ways-to-early-return-from-a-rails-controller/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539106/rails-render-and-exit-immediately and .... just google it :)

Comment: The first link confirms that it is indeed ok to do that, so thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is only possible with blocks, which have the capability to return directly the method which yields the block. Consider this example:

```
# You don't need to specify &block here, it works the same if you omit it
# I added it for clarity
def calling_method(&block)
  puts 'before'
  puts yield
  puts 'after'
end
```

Now, you can call the `calling_method` with different blocks and observe the behavior of the method:

First, we call it with a regular block which returns a simple value

```
calling_method { 3 }
# before
# 3
# after
# => nil
```

Now, we try what happens if you use the `next` keyword inside the block:

```
calling_method { next 23 }
# before
# 23
# after
# => nil
```

The `next` keyword is effectively a `return` for procs. It ends the execution of the proc and returns whatever value is given (or `nil` by default).

Finally, we have a look at what happens when we use `break` in the block:

```
p calling_method { break 23 }
# before
# => 23
```

When you use the `break` keyword in Ruby, what happens is that proc returns AND the method which yielded to the block also immediately returns with the value given to the `break` keyword.

Thus, if you can rewrite your logic so that the behavior currently defined in your `called_method` can be rewritten in a block and be passed to your `calling_method`, then you can control the return behavior from the block.

If you have to call the actual methods then the `called_method and return` technique is about the only way though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Returning from a lambda should continue the rest of the flow

```
def calling_method
  # stuff
  lambda { called_method }
  # more stuff
end
```